# Throttle with lodash isn't throttling using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, lodash, throttling

So I have this code

```
import React, { createRef, useEffect, useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { throttle } from 'lodash';
import { setProgress } from '../../helpers/markersApi';

const EXECUTE_EVERY_THIRTY_SECONDS = 30 * 1000; 
const throttledSetProgress = throttle(setProgress, EXECUTE_EVERY_THIRTY_SECONDS);

const Player = ({}) => {

  const updateProgress = (playerPosition, asset, immediateUpdate = false) => {
    if (asset.type !== 'EPG_PROGRAM') {
      const {
        id, episode,
      } = asset;
      const type = (episode && episode.episodeNumber) ? 'episode' : 'movie';

      if (immediateUpdate) {
        console.log('IMMEDIATE');
        // Cancel possible future invocations and set progress immediately
        throttledSetProgress.cancel();
        setProgress(id, playerPosition, type);
      } else {
        throttledSetProgress(id, playerPosition, type);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    updateProgress(position, playerAsset);
  }, [position, playerAsset]);
}
```

Problem is the the throttling isn't working since it's running the setProgress every time useEffect is called. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide the whole component, it seems like you are using the useEffect outside the component.

Answer (score 0):

The throttled function should remain the same between re-renderings, meaning we have to use React's UseCallback function. This works by changing throttledSetProgress from this:

```
const throttledSetProgress = throttle(setProgress, EXECUTE_EVERY_THIRTY_SECONDS);
```

To this:

```
const throttledSetProgress = useCallback(
  throttle(setProgress, EXECUTE_EVERY_THIRTY_SECONDS),
  [],
);
```

*(Don't forget to import useCallback from 'react' as well)*